# Enqueue scripts in footer

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-enqueue-script, footer

I'm trying to build a plugin and enqueue my scripts to footer. For performance reasons I'd like to load this plugin scripts after the functions.php scripts, because furthermore it will break the page otherwise.

I mean that in my functions.php there are essentials scripts like:

- jquery
- jquery-ui

which are loaded in the header. Next I have other essentials scripts, always in my functions.php, that are loaded in footer like:

-------FOOTER

- jquery-migrate
- hoverintent

etc... The problem is that when I load the plugin scriptS in footer they load just before the others in functions.php like:

------- FOOTER

- > HERE PLUGIN SCRIPTS
- jquery-migrate (from functions.php)
- hoverintent (from functions.php)

This makes the website break because some of the plugin scripts depends by the others loaded next. I guess it's a priority problem but I don't know how to handle that. I'm using the right hook for this according to codex:

```
wp_enqueue_script('typeahead bundle', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js', array('jquery', 'hoverintent') , false, true);
```

Even setting the array with dependencies it won't work.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the name (`typeahead bundle`) may contain spaces.

Comment: I've checked I did this mistake. Damn! That's great thank you!